# Get JSON tree based on the JSON paths list Java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

My input is something like:

```
List.of("customer.name", "customer.phone", "shop.address", "nr")
```

And I have to get the JSON tree hierarchy like:

```
{ 
  customer: {
    name: "",
    phone: "",
  },
  shop: {
    address: ""
  },
  nr: ""
}
```

I am using Java and 'org.json', 'com.jayway.jsonpath' JSON dependencies.

Do you have any ideas, please?
Thank you!

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176071/how-can-i-dynamically-create-json-from-many-dot-separated-strings-for-example-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

List<String> input = List.of("customer.name", "customer.phone", "shop.address", "nr");

JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

for (String s : input) {
  // Split the string by the '.' character to get the keys
  String[] keys = s.split("\\.");

  JSONObject obj = root;
  for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    String key = keys[i];
    if (i < keys.length - 1) {
      if (!obj.has(key)) {
        obj.put(key, new JSONObject());
      }
      obj = obj.getJSONObject(key);
    } else {
      obj.put(key, "");
    }
  }
}
```